# How to perform Basic Authorization using CURL and get a json/string response in terminal?

Tags: authentication, curl, server

```
  curl -X POST -u myusername:mypassword \
  -H "Authorization: Basic YXBpdXNlcjphcGlwd2Q=" \ 
  http://someapi.com/v1/auth/login


  //Ignore slashes.
```

I'm using this command in terminal but not getting the desired result.
Desired result should be a json, I think something is wrong with my paramenters.

Comment: Try use digest param *curl -X POST --digest --user <username>:<password> http://someapi.com/v1/auth/login -o output.json*

Comment: http://pastebin.com/31SvgwSD

Comment: 406 that your accept header is not acceptable. therefor i would add *-H "Accept: application/json"*

Comment: @venca still getting same error

Comment: Well I suggest you get more info. Then which API you want use...

Comment: @venca I've tried in hurl.it and it is working. I've used POST and in Authentication I've used Basic, Is something wrong with my parameters ? or the placement of parameters.

Comment: So are you using hurl.it instead of curl

Comment: @venca I'm using curl in terminal and hurl.it in browser..

Comment: Ok, and which API (web) are you trying to connect???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80396/discussion-between-whitefang-and-venca).